# The subgroup $\Omega_1$ of a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

I dont understand the concept of $\Omega_1(P)$ of a $p$-group!
I Know $\Omega_1(P)=\langle \lbrace x \in P | x^p=1 \rbrace \rangle$.
For example if $P$ is non-cyclic such that $P$ has atleast one cyclic maximal subgroup, then what can say about $\Omega_1(P)$.

Please Hint me. Thanks.

Comment: You can say $\Omega_1(P)$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: $p$-groups with a maximal cyclic subgroup are completely classified, so we could just split into cases (thought there is just one case for odd $p$). For $p=2$ you can get either extreme: The group could be dihedral and have it be the entire group or it could be (generalized) quaternion and have it be of order $2$.

Comment: thatks, can i say $ |\Omega_1(P)|=p^2$?

Comment: $|\Omega_1(P)|=p^2$ when $p$ is odd, but not necessarily when $p=2$.

Comment: @Derek Holt. that is isomorphic to $‍‍C_2 \times C_2$?

Comment: I said it not necessarily true that $|\Omega_1(P)|=p^2$ when $p=2$.

Comment: may i ask you explain any more? i want to understand this concept. thanks

Comment: ok it was a mistake, $C_p \times C_p$

Comment: Yes, when $p$ is odd, it is $C_p \times C_p$.

Comment: may i ask you explain it and write a proof( if $P$ is non-cyclic($p$ is odd) and has a cyclic maximal subgroup, $\Omega_1(P) \cong C_p \times C_p$).

Comment: in generality, $\Omega_1(P)$ is elementary abelian, always?

Comment: That last question was answered by my first comment.